# Spring boot - Actuator endpoints for services behind cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-gateway

How is it possible to visit service specific actuator endpoints where service is behind a cloud gateway?
For the spring cloud gateway, below is it's configuration
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>cloud-gateway-service</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.22</kotlin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

and for the `bootstrap.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8060

eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8061/eureka/

jwt:
  header:
    signature: changeme

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: MONGO_URL
      auto-index-creation: true
  cloud:
    gateway:
      filter:
        json-to-grpc:
          enabled: false
        circuit-breaker:
          enabled: false
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: first-service
          uri: lb://first-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/first/**
        - id: second-service
          uri: lb://second-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/second/**

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

And for `first-service`, here's the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>first-service</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>First Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.8.22</kotlin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Required to use PATCH -->
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-hc5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.microutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
            <artifactId>logcaptor</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

and here's first-service `bootstrap.yml`

```
server:
  port: 0
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-stacktrace: on_param
    include-exception: true

spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 125MB
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: MONGO_URL
  http:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson

eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8061/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 15
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 30

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'

feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 30000
        readTimeout: 30000
        loggerLevel: full
```

Now whenever I visit `http://localhost:8060/actuator`, I get a JSON response of all actuator endpoints as follows:

```
{
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator",
"templated": false
},
"beans": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/beans",
"templated": false
},
"caches-cache": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/caches/{cache}",
"templated": true
},
"caches": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/caches",
"templated": false
},
"health": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/health",
"templated": false
},
"health-path": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/health/{*path}",
"templated": true
},
"info": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/info",
"templated": false
},
"conditions": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/conditions",
"templated": false
},
"shutdown": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/shutdown",
"templated": false
},
"configprops": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/configprops",
"templated": false
},
"configprops-prefix": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/configprops/{prefix}",
"templated": true
},
"env": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/env",
"templated": false
},
"env-toMatch": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/env/{toMatch}",
"templated": true
},
"loggers": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/loggers",
"templated": false
},
"loggers-name": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/loggers/{name}",
"templated": true
},
"heapdump": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/heapdump",
"templated": false
},
"threaddump": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/threaddump",
"templated": false
},
"metrics-requiredMetricName": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
"templated": true
},
"metrics": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/metrics",
"templated": false
},
"scheduledtasks": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/scheduledtasks",
"templated": false
},
"mappings": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/mappings",
"templated": false
},
"refresh": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/refresh",
"templated": false
},
"features": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/features",
"templated": false
},
"serviceregistry": {
"href": "http://localhost:8060/actuator/serviceregistry",
"templated": false
}
}
}
```

But if I try `http://localhost:8060/actuator/first`, `http://localhost:8060/first/actuator`, it gives `404` or `405 GET Method not allowed`.

What else needs configuring to access `first-service` actuator endpoints?